# Python, Unicode and parsing with lxml and how to deal with 35\xa0new

Tags: python, html, unicode, lxml

I am extracting a field on a webpage ad the tag html text content looks like this...

```
35&nbsp;new
```

In python the extracted data looks like this...

```
35\xa0new
```

How to I deal with unicode in python to convert to a regular string?
"35 new"

what library to I use?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting unicode strings from the parser.  You can replace certain characters if you prefer others.  For example, your `\xa0` is a non-breaking space, and you can replace it with a regular space:

```
text = text.replace(u"\xa0", u" ")
```

There could be many of these characters that you want to change, so it might be a long process of finding all the ones that occur in your data.

Answer (score 3):

Avoid working with regular strings whenever possible; `unicode`s are generally more useful for text, and there are [many well-known solutions](http://farmdev.com/talks/unicode/) for manipulating and dealing with them.